# jQuery won't run again unless I reload the webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have created a contact form that I want to slide in from the right when I click a button and slide back when a separate button is clicked. So far I have only been able to get as far as the .hide() method, but when I click the button again to view the form it doesn't work. Can anyone explain why please?

Here is my html code

```
<div id="slidebottom" class="slide">            
<button id="button" class="btn btn-primary" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
</button>
<div class="well">
    <form action="index.html" method="post">
        <button id="close_button"><a><img id="close" src="img/close.png"></a></button>
        <h1 class="heading">CONTACT US</h1>
        <p>Register your interest and we will inform you of latest developments</p>

        <input type="text" id="name" name="user_name">
        <input type="email" id="email" name="user_email">
        <input type="tel" id="phone" name="user_number">

        <h1 class="register">REGISTER</h1>
    </form>
</div>
```

and my jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#button').click(function() {
    var $lefty = $(this).next();
    $lefty.animate({
      left: parseInt($lefty.css('left'),10) == 0 ?
        -$lefty.outerWidth() :
        0
    });
  });
});

$('#close_button').click(function() {
  $('.well').hide();
});
```

Comment: @PierreEmmanuelLallemant I don't think that's true.

Comment: why do you have a `$` sign before the `var`?

Comment: `.hide()` sets `display:none` for the element – you need to reverse that first, if you want to see it again.

Comment: One problem (among others) is that the close button is inside that `<form>`, so it will function as a "submit" button. Give it `type=button` to prevent that.

Comment: So your question is why cannot you see a hidden element?!...

Comment: @Pointy Good point and a button cannot contains an anchor. EDIT: no href set, so not sure it is interactive element but anyway doesn't make sense

Comment: Second, after clicking the (fixed) "close" button, the "left" CSS property of that hidden `<div>` is "auto", which is probably not what your code expects.

Comment: Im pretty new to jQuery as its the first time I have used it in a project, so you will have to explain in very basic terms haha

Comment: Matt ..when learning how to manipulate UI display make sure you learn how to inspect the live html in browser dev tools. You can see all the css rules for each element and are able to edit those as well. Same for the inline style created by various methods like `hide()`

Comment: Please provide a minimalistic demo to make it clearer what behaviour you're exactly talking about.

Comment: maybe I wasn't clear enough. Basically I have a contact button in the top right of my web page. When I click it, a contact form appears from the right. To close the form there is a X button on the top left of the form itself which is a .hide(). Ideally I'd like it to slide back to where it came from (which is my first issue). The second and main issue is when I click the contact button again, the jQuery doesn't work unless I physically refresh the web browser and I don't understand why.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#button').click(function() {
    var $lefty = $(this).next();
    $('.well').show();
    $lefty.animate({
      left: parseInt($lefty.css('left'),10) == 0 ?
        -$lefty.outerWidth() :
        0
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Ok but how could OP clicks on hidden element??? `#close_button` is child of `.well`

Comment: you're right, I modified the code with a totally other concept